# trigger alert on button click with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two textfields with different IDs as shown

```
<textarea id="textfield">Hello World</textarea>
```

This will be updated with the content of the first textarea

```
<input id="messageID">
```

This is my script

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function() {

    var value = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
    document.getElementById('#messageID').val(value);
  alert(value);

}              
</script>
```

This is the onclick button and nothing happens when I click it

```
<button onclick="myfunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="button">Alert</button>
```

Kindly assist!

Comment: Change `.val(value);` to `.value = value;` . Also name your function: `function myfunction() {`

Comment: Try to name your function myfunction(){ var value = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
    document.getElementById('#messageID').val(value);
  alert(value);}

Comment: Nothing happens still

Comment: Remove the sharp `#` from `document.getElementById('#messageID')`

Comment: Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/x7av4m96/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
function myfunction() {

  var value = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
    document.getElementById('messageID').value=value;
  alert(value);

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Alert" onclick="myfunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="button"/>
<textarea id="textfield">Hello World</textarea>

<input id="messageID">
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things I'm seeing wrong:

1. `.val(value);` is a jQuery' method, not javascript... you should change it to `.value = value;`
2. to call `onclick="myfunction()"` you should name it: `var myfunction = function(){`
3. The `document.getElementById()` method doesn't need sharp `#` before the name.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
The most important catch is whenever you declare function on button click you should define that function inside javascript.

<script type=text/javascript>
function myfunction() {

    var value = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
    document.getElementById("messageID").value = value;
    alert(value);

}              
</script>
<textarea id="textfield">Hello World</textarea>
<input id="messageID">
<button onclick="myfunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="button">Alert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go a working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/blazeeboy/fNPvf/

Its inner Html you are trying to get

```
<textarea id="textfield">Hello World</textarea>
<input id="messageID"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="button"    onclick="myfunction()">Alert</button>

function myfunction(){
    alert(1);
    var v = document.getElementById("textfield").innerHTML ;
   document.getElementById('messageID').innerHTML = v;
  alert(v);
}
```